# How to use OneOf with two similiar schemas in OpenApi?

Tags: schema, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the following schema in openapi

```
/submit:
post:
  description: Submit info
  x-openapi-router-controller: abc.def
  operationId: submit_info
  requestBody:
    description: Submit request
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubmitRequest'
  responses:
    200:
      description: submitted successfully
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooResponse'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BarResponse'
FooResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - id
    - value
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      description: id
      example: '1234'
    value:
      type: string
      description: value
      example: 'foo'
BarResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - id
    - value
    - data
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      description: id
      example: '1234'
    value:
      type: string
      description: value
      example: 'foo'
    data:
      type: object
      required:
        - transaction_id
      description: Data associated bar response
      properties:
        transaction_id:
          type: string
          description: transaction id
          example: 'c2345'
```

So I have FooResponse and BarResponse. I am getting OneOf matches multiple schema error though I have different required items in FooResponse and BarResponse. It seems like openapi matches two schemas even if there are additional required items in one of the schema.

Is there a way to fix this? I want to use OneOf, but not sure how to differentiate these two schema.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenAPI [Schema Object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#schema-object) has a property called `additionalProperties` that specifies if properties not defined in the schema are allowed anyway in the instances(those properties are ignored).

Default value for `additionalProperties` is `true` which will cause both `FooResponse` and `BarResponse` to be valid for your instances.
Setting `additionalProperties` to `false` on `FooResponse` should solve the problem.

If you don't want to disallow additional properties you would have to introduce some kind of `type` property in both objects and use a [Discriminator Object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#discriminator-object).